# Is the circumcenter of an equilateral triangle equidistant from its 3 vertices?

Tags: geometry

Is the circumcenter of an equilateral triangle equidistant from its 3 vertices? If yes, how can I prove that?

Comment: http://hotmath.com/hotmath_help/topics/circumcenter-theorem.html   But have you really mean this as this proposition  holds true for any triangle

Comment: No, its okay. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The circle and equilateral triangle both are symmetric figures.When circumcircle is drawn on equilateral triangle,the centre of the circle will be equidistant from 3 of it's vertices by symmetry.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that's true for **any** triangle.
The circumcircle of a triangle is a circle which passes through its vertices:
[image]

Since the centre of a cirle is equidistant from all point *on* the circle, it follows that the circumcentre is equidistant from the vertices.

In the case of an equilateral triangle, all the geometrical centres of the triange coincide. That means that not only the circumcentre, but the *incentre*, *orthocentre* and *centroid* are equidistant from the vertices too.

This isn't the case for other triangles.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The circumcenter is the center of the circle passing through the vertices. So it is exactly at a distance $r$ away from the vertices. $r$ is the radius of the circumcircle.